# jquery-ui autocomplete gives 'not a function' error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've been having so many problems trying to get an autocomplete implementation working that I decided to go back to a simple case. I copied and pasted the code from the Demo [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), and got exactly the same error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function.

The code as I copied it

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

   <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The jquery-ui library looks to have been loaded, I can see the contents in the Debugger: [image: Screenshot of Debugger]

Is there something I'm missing?

I'm using Firefox on a Windows 11 system, no firewall or other things to get in the way. jquery.js and jquery-ui.js seem to load without a problem.

Comment: The error means that the jQuery UI Library has not been loaded. Hence the `$(selector).autocomplete()` is not defined. Please examine your Headers and ensure that you have properly included the Script Source. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If I can see the contents of the jQuery UI library in debugger I assume that means it's loaded?

Comment: I have windows 10, but that example code, as-is, works for me with Firefix v102.0.1. Though it might seem silly, try moving the `<script>` block with the tag list and autocomplete down to the point between the closing `</div>` the closing `</body>` tags to see if that makes any difference. Side note, not causing the trouble, but their example line with `resources/demos/...` can be removed, as that gives a 404 warning: `GET http://localhost/resources/demos/style.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 6ms]`

Comment: @user3325003 it does appear to be loading yet it is not ready when you call Autocomplete. Or there is some other pert of your code breaking JavaScript that is preventing this from loading properly.

Comment: You were right, Twisty. I hadn't twigged that the bootstrap code in the Shared page also loaded jquery.js. A trap for not-so-young-but-novice web coders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project has bootstrap code in the Shared page which also loads jquery. That was the conflict.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).